# can file.renameTo replace a existing file?

Tags: java, file, file-io

```
// File (or directory) to be moved
File file = new File("filename");

// Destination directory
File dir = new File("directoryname");

// Move file to new directory
boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
if (!success) {
    // File was not successfully moved
    //can it be because file with file name already exists in destination?
}
```

If the file with name 'filename' already exists in the destination will it be replaced with a new one?

Comment: Why don't you test it out and find out? Do you wish to know if the behaviour is different on different environments?

Comment: @wjans @aldrin Of course he could test this. But I for one prefer documentation in a combination with tests

Comment: Documentation from where? A link to some forum? as opposed to an actual experimental *fact?*

Comment: @EJP as @stacker wrote, there is documentation of the method in Javadoc. I am not saying that documentation is better than tests. But sometimes there might be exceptions in the documentation that you will not test. The documentation can really help you to find out what to test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

> Many **aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent**: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and **it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists**. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

From Javadoc:

> The rename operation might not be able
>   to move a file from one filesystem to
>   another, it might not be atomic, and
>   it might not succeed if a file with
>   the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists.

I tested the following code:

It works the first time, second time it fails as expected.
To move a file you should delete or rename the destination if required.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File( "c:\\filename" );
        file.createNewFile();
        File dir = new File( "c:\\temp" );
        boolean success = file.renameTo( new File( dir, file.getName() ) );
        if ( !success ) {
            System.err.println( "succ:" + success );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is system dependent **you should not expect** it to behave this or other way. Check it and implement your own logic.